# Linear regression with unknown x coordinates

Tags: regression, linear

My situation is that I have 3 data points - I know the $y$ coordinate of each, and know a relationship between the $x$ coordinates. Let's say the coordinates $(x,y)$ in question are:

$(k,1), (5k,2), (10k, 3)$

where $k$ is some unknown constant.

If I also know that the graph should go through the origin, is it possibly to come up with a regression equation?

I originally had the idea to just let $k$ be some number, then slowly shift the curve until the y-intercept hit 0, but excel didn't like that at all. I thought about forcing the intercept, but that doesn't solve the problem, just adds another data point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I also know that the graph should go through the origin, is it possible to come up with a regression equation?

No.

If you know the line goes through the origin, you know that $E(y)=cx$. [Presumably also you have reason to think that the variance of the error term is related to the $x$, though I'll see what I can do without that.]

Now we add that $x^\text{obs}=kx$ (we only see $x$ up to a scaling constant).

So you observe pairs $(kx_i, cx_i+e_i)$

Note that you can estimate the ratio $c/k$ but there is nothing here that indicates the individual $c$ and $k$ values.

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Makes things annoying, now I have to actually put effort into my measurements!

Thanks for the help!